# different name-based hosts on the same ip

Tags: apache, centos, httpd.conf

I need to access a wordpress that I will install without a domain, for that I created another ip address to have all name-based hosts on the same ip, but when i restart the httpd service it is return several warnings and all the domains point to the first.

```
        Starting httpd: [Thu Aug 15 19:22:58 2013] 
    [warn] VirtualHost 176.111.104.95:80 overlaps with VirtualHost 176.111.104.95:80,
 the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive

    [Thu Aug 15 19:22:58 2013] 
    [warn] VirtualHost 176.111.104.95:80 overlaps with VirtualHost 176.111.104.95:80, 
the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive



<VirtualHost 176.111.104.95:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@carviz.pt
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/carviz.pt/public_html
    ServerName carviz.pt
    ServerAlias www.carviz.pt
    ErrorLog logs/carviz.pt-error_log
    CustomLog logs/carviz.pt-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 176.111.104.95:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@instaclasse.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/instaclasse.com/public_html
    ServerName instaclasse.com
    ServerAlias www.instaclasse.com
    ErrorLog logs/instaclasse.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/instaclasse.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 176.111.104.95:80>
    ServerAdmin ftpaul@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/skala.pt/public_html
    ServerName skala.pt
    ServerAlias www.skala.pt
    ErrorLog logs/skala-error_log
    CustomLog logs/skala-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I was following this example: Mixed name-based and IP-based vhosts on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score -1):

you can look at `ports.conf` in `/etc/apache2`

you can add some lines there:

```
NameVirtualhost 176.111.104.95:80
Listen 176.111.104.95:80
```

or better yet (if you areonly using one ip)

you can change your current virtualhost from

```
<VirtualHost 176.111.104.95:80>
```

to